# richfaces data-table error

Tags: ajax, datatable, richfaces

I am new to `richfaces`.

I have a problem with rich:datatable filtering, the source code of my page is like the site example:

```
<h:form id="form">

        <rich:dataTable keepSaved="true" id="richTable" var="record" value="#{citiesBean}" rows="20">           

          <rich:column >

        <f:facet name="header">

            <h:commandLink action="#{bean.toggleSort}">

                #{bean.sortOrders['cityTitle']}    

                <a4j:ajax render="richTable" />

                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.sortProperty}" value="#{'cityTitle'}" />

            </h:commandLink>

            <br />

            <h:inputText value="#{citiesBean.filterValues['cityTitle']}">

                <a4j:ajax render="richTable@body scroller" event="keyup" />

            </h:inputText>

        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{record['cityTitle']}" />

    </rich:column>

<rich:column >

        <f:facet name="header">

            <h:commandLink action="#{bean.toggleSort}">

                #{bean.sortOrders['cityCode']}    

                <a4j:ajax render="richTable" />

                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.sortProperty}" value="#{'cityCode'}" />

            </h:commandLink>

            <br />

            <h:inputText value="#{citiesBean.filterValues['cityCode']}">

                <a4j:ajax render="richTable@body scroller" event="keyup" />

            </h:inputText>

        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{record['cityCode']}" />

    </rich:column>

            <f:facet name="footer">

                <rich:dataScroller id="scroller" />

            </f:facet>

        </rich:dataTable>

    </h:form>
```

everything seems OK but it has some problems.

1- `datascroller` does not work without render attribute set to 'richTable' but it works on demo!!!

2-when i type something on filter input, the table does not get updated!, i have checked the request and response on firebug,

the response does not have a valid id, i mean it look like this:

```
<update id="form:richTable:tb">&lt;tbody id="form:richTable:0:tb" ....
```

what is wrong with my codes?!

I am using, richfaces 4, Glassfish 3.1, Firefox 3.6

thanks in advance.

Comment: even i m stuck in d same problem. Can u share your filterValues method of citiesBean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was a kind of bug. Now it is fine with version 4.1 M1.